# Compilation Error in ASP.NET Code when adding a Literal Control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm trying to format a `literal` control on a code-behind page:

```
BillerLiteral.Text = "<p class="'no-margin'"/>" + attendee1.FirstName + " " + 
attendee1.LastName + "</p> <p class=""no-margin"">" + attendee1.Address1 + "," + 
attendee1.Address2 + "</p><p class=""margin"">" + attendee1.City + "," + 
attendee1.State + " " + attendee1.ZipCode + "</p><p>" + attendee1.Email + "</p>";
```

Right after I added that line, I get compilation errors even though it compiles fine.

```
Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a 
resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific 
error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code 1.
```

Here's the detailed compiler output:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE> "c:\Window
\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows
\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089
\System.ServiceModel.dll" 
/R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data
\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL
\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089
\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System
\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL
\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35
\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\
System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\
System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
/R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel
\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly
\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:
"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
\System.Web.Mobile.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml
\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll" 
/R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web
\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" 
/R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35
\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL
\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089
\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Users\jeffreyeas\AppData\Local
\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\awchallenge\ae85f60c\8aef9183\App_Code.fkizkk6y.dll"
 /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089
\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web
\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /out:"C:\Users\jeffreyeas\AppData\Local
\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\awchallenge\ae85f60c\8aef9183
\App_Web_page_two.aspx.cdcab7d2.dkslispb.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- 
/win32res:"C:\Users\jeffreyeas\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\awchallenge
\ae85f60c\8aef9183\vuyv4kby.res" /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 /warnaserror-
"C:\Users\jeffreyeas\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\awchallenge\ae85f60c
\8aef9183\App_Web_page_two.aspx.cdcab7d2.dkslispb.0.cs" "C:\Users\jeffreyeas\AppData
\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\awchallenge\ae85f60c\8aef9183
\App_Web_page_two.aspx.cdcab7d2.dkslispb.1.cs" "C:\Users\jeffreyeas\AppData\Local
\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\awchallenge\ae85f60c\8aef9183
\App_Web_page_two.aspx.cdcab7d2.dkslispb.2.cs"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you use string.Format your code will be more performant and easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quotes are wrong in `"<p class="'no-margin'"/>"`

Comment: Also, it looks like that tag is self-closing.

Answer (score 1):

```
BillerLiteral.Text = "<p class=\"no-margin\"/>" + attendee1.FirstName + " " + attendee1.LastName + "</p> <p class=\"no-margin\">" + attendee1.Address1 + "," + attendee1.Address2 + "</p><p class=\"margin\">" + attendee1.City + "," + attendee1.State + " " + attendee1.ZipCode + "</p><p>" + attendee1.Email + "</p>";
```

try this